# What is the most relavant math for statistics students?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, soft-question, advice

As they say "the more math you learn the better". Unfortunately, I did not have a lot of mathematical training in my undergraduate. Now I am doing a master in mathematics, mainly to make up some necessary background knowledge in mathematics in order to do my statistics. So far I have done metric space analysis, group and ring, and two numerical computation courses. Now I am considering what subjects to take next semester. So far I have decided to do topological analysis, probability theory. I am not sure whether it is useful to take more algebra course like Galois Theory. Any suggestion, general or specific, would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: No measure theory yet? functional analysis?

Comment: Measure theory would be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Measure theory will be included in topology and probability theory. And functional analysis is on my list but will be taken in the second half of 2014.

Comment: Probability theory for sure.